# OpenCV with Objective C vs Objective C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

When using OpenCV for iOS projects, most articles on the internet recommends changing `.m` to `.mm`.

However, since Objective C is a strict superset of C++, why do we need to do this change? Even worse, without changing `.m` to `.mm`, `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C is **not** a superset of C++.  Changing .m to .mm changes the file from Objective-C to Objective-C++, which is a superset of C++.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler need to know what type of code is dealing with.

By using .mm the compiler expects Obj-C and C++.
By using .m it only expects Obj-C

The compilation is handled differently according to the file extension.